# Redirect files in uploads directory if WordPress user not logged in

Tags: htaccess, regex

I would like to redirect all of the following urls if a WordPress user is not logged in (or WordPress cookie is set) using .htaccess.

1. `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sample_pdf`
2. `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sample_pdf/index.html`
3. `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sample_pdf/index.html#page=1`
4. `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sample_pdf/index.html#page=2` etc etc

This is what I have tried :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?/?)wp-content/uploads/sample_pdf/(.+) [NC]
    RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/wp-login.php?redirect_to=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?/?)wp-content/uploads/sample_pdf/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/wp-login.php?redirect_to=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Both of these options redirect the first URL :

- `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sample_pdf`

But not the others.

Can you please let me know where my regex is going wrong & why it's not grabbing everything in the `/sample_pdf` directory.

Comment: "Both of these options redirect the first URL" - Although it shouldn't _directly_, as the regex in the 2nd condition does not match (in both rule blocks). Is `sample_pdf` a physical directory on the filesystem? In which case, mod_dir would first issue a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash - then (on the redirected/2nd request) it would match. But this also depends on where exactly you've put these directives in relation to other directives in your `.htaccess` file - order matters. Please update your question with the contents of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Also, why are you capturing the URL-path _before_ `wp-content/`? And why are you appending this to the _hostname_ (or start of the URL-path)? From the example URLs given this would result in an erroneous double slash at the start of the URL-path. (?)